# Where is the 10240 SDK in Visual Studio 16.0.0 Preview 4.0?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml

Hi I was testing yesterday the new version of Visual Studio 16.0.0 Preview 4.0 and I noticed the UWP development SDK 10240 is not included there:

[image]

Does someone know if this is just because it's a preview and it's finally gonna be included in the RC versions? Couln't find it in the current installer but it is in the previews versions.

Thanks.

Comment: That is a very old SDK version, the first one for Win10.  It wasn't getting installed by VS2017 anymore either.  You'll have to install it yourself.  But consider to update your project instead.

Comment: It is a very old SDK but people an organizations are still using it and Microsoft is supporting it until 2025 according to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history

Comment: Sure, that's why it is so easy to download.  Let Google help you, query for "windows 10 sdk previous versions" and take the first hit.

Comment: Tried to find it before I posted this question in this link: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive I Can't manage to find the 10240 version there.